# Metric in an ordered field

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose that we have $ \mathbb{F} $ an ordered field with a metric d and $x,y \in \mathbb{F} $ non negative numbers. It is possible to affirm that if $ x \leq y $ then $d (x,0) \leq d(y,0) $?

If we think in $ \mathbb{R} $ , we can easily see it is true using the distance as usually. But how to prove this is true for any metric? I couldn't find a counter example.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt this is the case unless the topology induced by the metric is the same as that induced by the ordering (although this may be false). I'll try to think of a counterexample.

Comment: @Daniel Rust Ok Daniel, thank you. But if we are talking sbout the metric induced my the order, can we prove it is true?

Comment: What is the metric induced by the order?

Comment: I don't know, I mean't if we had a relation between the metric and the order. Can't we give a general case, in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ if $x\neq 0\neq y$ and $d(x,0)=d(0,x)=\sqrt{1+(10-x)^2}$ if $x\neq 0$, and $d(0,0)=0$.

This is the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ but we've picked up the origin and moved it to $(10,1)$ if we consider $\mathbb{R}$ to be the $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The above metric is the induced metric from this embedding in to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$d(10,0)=1$ but $d(9,0)=\sqrt{2}$ which contradicts your condition.

The problem here is that there's no condition relating the metric and the ordering, so we can essentially embed our field in to any metric space of the same cardinality.

Comment: Right, but if we had a relation between the metric and order? Could we prove that the affirmation is true?

Comment: You might like to make a new question to ask that.

Comment: Hm, ok. I will try to make using this "particular" case before asking again. But I have no idea how to use the information x <= y if I have no metric to work with.